# Apt-get unable to locate package

Tags: raspbian-jessie, apt

I am trying to install php7.0 on jessie and running into a problem.

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install php7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
```

I have also tried installing `php-fpm` with the same result.

My sources.list looks like this

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

I can see the package I am after here http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/

I have tried running `sudo apt update` and also `sudo apt-get upgrade` as suggested on other topics but cannot find a solution.

What's odd is I installed the nginx package with `sudo apt-get install nginx` and this worked without any problem. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: If you are happy using an obsolete OS you should be OK with a slightly older php (which is little different from 7.0)

Answer (score 0):

That pool contains packages that are part of all the distro versions that are still actively maintained:

- v.8, jessie
- v.8, stretch (aka. "oldstable")
- v.9, buster (aka. "stable")

And possibly things from v.10, Bullseye aka. testing.  If you use the [online Debian search tool](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) (Raspbian being a variant of Debian), you can search for things in any of them, which reveals [php7.0 is available in oldstable](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=php7.0&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) (stretch) only.

You can try and install .debs from other versions directly (download them and use `dpkg -i`), but no one promises they will work, and chances are you will have to unravel dependencies the same way.